# tocloft: undefined error

Tags: table-of-contents, tocloft

I'm getting an `undefined` error for `\cftchapfont` (and all other `tocloft` options). I haven't found this problem documented elsewhere, which leads me to suspect that I'm missing something simple.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\LARGE\scshape}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{first chapter}
\section{second chapter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: "chap" means chapter, and there are no chapter in the article class, use book or report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the article class has no chapters, the solution is to (a) use a different document class, or (b) use \cftsecfont.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\LARGE\scshape}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{first section}
\section{second section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The same thing happens in the `memoir` class, too.